# How save Image State of a ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, imagepicker

Hi I'm developing an app where the user have to set an image in ImageView. But when the app is restarted the ImageView automatically resets to default. Now I would like to know how to save the state of the ImageView which the user sets. I'm using this Library to set the Image:- https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can save image in `SharedPreferences` and then reload it.

### Try This

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bm = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT); 


SharedPreferences.Editor ed1 = getSharedPreferences("image",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                ed1.putString("image", encoded);
                                ed1.apply();
```

Now to set Image to ImageView Again

```
SharedPreferences gm = getSharedPreferences("image", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String ot = cashinuser.getString("cashinuser", "");

String tmp = "";

byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(tmp.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
ImageView image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
```